# Call storyboard scene programmatically in iOS 7 (without needing segue)?

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

Can anyone provide me source code to call storyboard programatically in iOS 7 without using any segue. I am new to iPhone development. 
Thank in advance
i am using like this :

```
UIViewController *pageOneController = [[UIViewController alloc]init] ;
[self.presentedViewController:pageOneController animated:YES completion:nil];

NSString * storyboardName = @"Main.Storyboard";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pageOne"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and i am getting this error:
[self.presentedViewController:pageOneController animated:YES completion:nil]; has error saying No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector ':animated:completion:'

Comment: What is the problem with your code? What is happening? Does it crash your app?

Comment: [self.presentedViewController:pageOneController animated:YES completion:nil]; has error saying No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector ':animated:completion:'

Comment: please add that information to your question.

Comment: @Thedude can you provide me a source file if you have done it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on this:

```
UIStoryboard *theStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *theViewController = [theStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"];
```

And then you can just push the view using modal presentation.

But my recommendation is to get rid of Storyboards and go directly to code the interfaces with Objective-C. You'll have a better performance and control over them. And if you're learning about Objective-C programming you'll find coding interfaces, more interesting and educational than create them with Storyboards.

Comment: it didnot work :( can u provide me a file u have done i can learn from it :)

Comment: Don't copy/paste. This code I posted it's just an example. You must change the variable names and make them suitable for your project.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting has nothing to do with Storyboard. Your code is a big mess and this is the line that crashes your app:

```
[self.presentedViewController:pageOneController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

From the error message you can understand, that `presentedViewController` property does not respond to this selector `animated:completion:`. So what you are doing wrong here is probably referencing the `presentedViewController` property instead of calling `presentViewController` method.

Try fixing this line with:

```
[self presentViewController:pageOneController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Notice the difference that I removed the dot between `self` and `presentViewController` and changed from `presentedViewController` to `presentViewController`. This is the correct call and I am assuming that `self` is some kind of `UIViewController` class.

Comment: I got this error, what does it means?
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'page1ViewController' in bundle NSBundle

Comment: Exactly what it says. You are instantiating a storyboard with `page1ViewController` name somewhere and it obviously does not exist.